# How to compose a binary function with a unary function?

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I feel like I'm overlooking something totally obvious here but what is the correct way (if any) to use point-free notation for composing a binary function and a unary function?  For example, the following code compiles:

```
sortedAppend :: (Ord a) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
sortedAppend xs ys = sort $ xs ++ ys
```

but the following code does not compile:

```
sortedAppend :: (Ord a) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
sortedAppend = sort . (++)
```

Are we able to compose `(++)` with `sort` (in the order shown above)?  If so, how?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think that any of these solutions (mine or the others) is that pretty, but I prefer....

```
let sortedAppend = (sort .) . (++)
```

The reason I prefer this is because it is easy for me to think of....  If you ignore the parenthesis, you basically need to add an extra (.) for each parameter

```
f . g --one parameter
f . . g --two params
f . . . g --three params
```

which makes sense, since `g x` returns a function with N-1 inputs....

....but those needed parens make it so ugly....

```
((f .) .) . g
```

Comment: The [SEC](http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators) perspective: `result = (.)`, then `result f g`, `(result.result) f g`, `(result.result.result) f g`

Answer (score 16):

Just for the sake of completeness let's actually take your example and gradually make it point free.

First, remember `(f . g) x = f (g x)`. Then there is Eta-reduction `(\x -> f x) ≡ f`. Last useful thing is [operator section](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Section_of_an_infix_operator).
Using these rules we can go like this:

```
sortedAppend xs ys = sort $ xs ++ ys        -- original function
sortedAppend xs ys = sort (xs ++ ys)        -- remove $
sortedAppend xs ys = sort ((++) xs ys)      -- prefix application of ++
sortedAppend xs ys = (sort . ((++) xs)) ys  -- definition of composition
sortedAppend xs = sort . (++) xs            -- eta reduction
sortedAppend xs = (sort .) ((++) xs)        -- operator section
sortedAppend xs = ((sort .) . (++)) xs      -- definition of composition
sortedAppend = (sort .) . (++)              -- eta reduction
```

Answer (score 12):

You *could* use the "owl-operator" (sometimes called breast.operator too I think):

```
Prelude> :t (.).(.)
(.).(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> a1 -> b) -> a -> a1 -> c
```

BUT: I don't think you should - what you wrote is very readable - using this:

```
sortedAppend = ((.).(.)) sort (++)
```

is not IMO

PS: yeah you could do

```
(.:.) = (.).(.)
sortedAppend = sort .:. (++)
```

but still .... not digestible

PPS: I just found out that this operator is defined as `(.:)` in a package called [pointless-fun](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointless-fun-1.1.0.5/docs/Data-Function-Pointless.html) ^^

Comment: One other possibility: `sortedAppend xs = sort . (xs ++)`

Comment: A more generalized form of `(.).(.)` is `fmap fmap fmap`.  Keep in mind that this can be turned into ```fmap `fmap` fmap```, which is equivalent to `fmap . fmap`, but I like the first version best.  This will let you do something like `(+1) .: [Just 1, Nothing, Just 2]` and get `[Just 2, Nothing, Just 3]`, or something like `sequence $ length .: replicate 3 getLine` (might be better as `fmap length $ replicateM 3 getLine`), but there are other uses for the operator.  Essentially all it does is map a function 2 `Functor` layers deep.

Comment: @bheklilr I *love* this - but to reproduce it I would have to remember the tripple-flip or reinvent it - due to some *strange* reason I can remember the `(.).(.)` without any problem ;)

Answer (score 8):

I don’t think I’d personally recommend adding dependencies for things like that, but there is also

```
(.:) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
```

in [`Data.Composition`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/composition/docs/Data-Composition.html) in the package [`composition`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/composition).